# Karate UI "no such session' Error in Linux using LinuxChromeDriver

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline, webdriver, karate

I am running Karate UI scripts on a remote Linux server to trouble shoot for Jenkins CD Pipeline functional test implementation.

I have my karate-config set up to point to different executable paths depending on the OS:

```
 if (os.type.equalsIgnoreCase('windows')) {
//    UNCOMMENT OUT THE 3 LINES BELOW TO SIMULATE HEADLESS PIPELINE UI TEST
        var driverPath = 'src/main/resources/drivers/WindowsChromeDriver.exe'
        var session = { capabilities: { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [ '--headless=new', 'start-maximized', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-impl-side-painting' ] } } } }
        karate.configure('driver', {readTimeout: 120000, type: 'chromedriver',  webDriverSession: session, executable: driverPath, userDataDir: null })

//   COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW IF LINES ABOVE ARE UNCOMMENTED OUT TO SIMULATE HEADLESS PIPELINE UI TEST
//        karate.configure('driver', { type: 'chrome',  executable: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' })
        karate.log("OS type is set to: ", os.type, "With a path of:", driverPath);
    } else if (os.type.equalsIgnoreCase('linux')) {
            var driverPath = 'src/main/resources/drivers/LinuxChromeDriver.chromedriver';
            var session = { capabilities: { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [ '--headless', 'start-maximized', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-impl-side-painting' ] } } } }
            karate.configure ('driver', {readTimeout: 120000, type: 'chromedriver',  webDriverSession: session, executable: driverPath, userDataDir: null })
            karate.log("OS type is set to: ", os.type, "With a path of:", driverPath);
    }
     else {
            karate.log("NON-VALID OS value passed in to run from: ", os.type);
        }

     if (!os.type) {
             os.type = 'windows';
             karate.log("An OS value was not provided and it has been set to the default of:", os.type);
     }
```

I have been running this quick feature just to make sure my script works

```
Background:
    * configure retry = { count: 5, interval: 5000 }
    * configure afterScenario = function(){ if (karate.info.errorMessage) driver.screenshot() }
    * call read('../UISetup/0.2_HITRequest1099SSA.feature')
    * def loginButton = "//*[@id='content']/div[3]/div/form/div[1]/button"

  Scenario: Log into application with valid credentials
    * driver baseUrl
    * def sessionId = driver.sessionId
    * print 'The session ID for this test is:', sessionId
    * delay(2000)
    * clear('input[name=username')
    * clear('input[name=password')
    * input('input[name=username', Username)
    * input('input[name=password', Pswrd)
    * delay(2000)
    * highlight(loginButton)
    * submit().click(loginButton)
    * def sessionIdCheck = driver.sessionId
    * print 'The session ID for this test is:', sessionIdCheck
    * def homeUrl = driver.url
    * print "The UI login was successful and we are on the HOME page:", homeUrl

    * click('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button')
    * delay(2000)

    * def getStartUrl = driver.url
    * print "The begin validating button was clicked and we are now on the GETTING STARTED page:", getStartUrl
```

When I run this headless locally on a Windows machine I have no issues.  However, headless on Linux (remote server or pipeline) I am getting the following error in the console.

```
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The session ID for this test is: 7c949948ec8a6c46bd6a2207f7356d00
    [pool-2-thread-4] WARN com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - waiting for document to change: failed after 5 retries and 2696 milliseconds
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The UI login was successful and we are on the HOME page: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"}
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The begin validating button was clicked and we are now on the GETTING STARTED page: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"}
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The loan number has been entered in the input field and we are now on the SPECIFIC SEARCH page: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"}
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] We have clicked the VALIDATE button and are now on the VALIDATE page with a URL: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"} for request ID: 151
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The loan number in validation is: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"}
    [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] The UI SSN number is: {"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 x86_64)"}
```

One strange behavior is that I don't believe the script is even running in Chrome but my tests are passing.  I don't have any matches or anything but I would assume that the tests would fail because the web elements couldn't be located

[Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqiGB.png)

Has anyone experienced this error before and have a resolution?  I know I'm using an ancient LinuxChromeDriver (2.40) but that's the one we're required to use in our CD pipeline for now.

***************************UPDATE***************************__

Per suggestion, I did not have a chome binary installed on Linux.  However, when I run the same test in Jenkins CD, I get this error

> Blockquote [pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] the driver has been configured using {
> "type": "chrome",
> "executable": "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
> "userDataDir": null,
> "addOptions": [
> "--ignore-certificate-errors",
> "--headless",
> "--window-size=1600,900"
> ]
> }

```
[pool-2-thread-4] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] When we navigate to the base URL www.testurl.com
[chrome_1677897312898] WARN com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 132 - [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --disable-popup-blocking, --ignore-certificate-errors, --headless, --window-size=1600,900]
[pool-2-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 2 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9222
[pool-2-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[pool-2-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 1 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9222
```

This is my driver configuration:

> Blockquote                config.driverConfig = { type: 'chrome', executable: '/usr/bin/google-chrome', addOptions : ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--headless', '--window-size=1600,900']}

And this is the information that I get printed to the console from the Jenkins node:

- ls -a /usr/bin/google-chrome
- /usr/bin/google-chrome
- whereis google-chrome
- google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz
- google-chrome --version
- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106

Comment: #1 Could you share us a hello world or [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your test ? #2 Also you use docker #3 Is chrome installed in the jenkins server? #4 Is a linux server version or a linux with desktop?

Comment: I have no idea, generally I recommend not using headless, although that may change in the future: https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/1628439484043001856

Comment: Thanks!  JRichardsz.  I did not have a chrome binary installed.  I was able to get my tests to return the URL

Comment: @PeterThomas Thank you for the insane amount of responses you do here!  I absolutely love Karate/KarateUI.  I have not come across an issue that it couldn't test for.  Really incredible work and very grateful.